# Freecodecamp - Counting Cards

Tags: javascript

I know there are a number of ways to complete this challenge and I can simply  a different approach to pass the requirement however I am struggling to understand what's wrong with my code.

Challenge - https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/counting-cards/

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    var count = 0;

    function cc(card) {
      // Only change code below this line

      if (card < 7){
        count++;
      } else if (card < 10){
        count+=0;
      } else (count--;)

      if (count > 0){
        return count + " Bet";
      } else (
        return count + " Hold";
      )
      // Only change code above this line
    }

    // Add/remove calls to test your function.
    // Note: Only the last will display
    cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

Comment: Whats the question here?

Comment: Well, what *is* wrong with your code? Error? If so, which and where? Wrong result? If so, which, and what were you expecting? Elephants in the living room? If so, how many, and when did they appear?

Comment: *When someone asks a question about a problem with their code, we need to know what is wrong with it. Stating that “it doesn’t work” is not helpful.*, please read and [follow the instructions from here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: the code isn't executing the required outcome i.e. it does nothing, I have updated with the link to the challenge, my apologies. I had a few tab's open

Comment: What is this: `count+=0;` suppose to do?

Comment: OT: Not that it's an error but `else (count--;)` is not very readable. You should not use parentheses there (and in the other `else` clause further down).

Comment: *If you do not know why your code did not work, that suggests you have not debugged it. Debugging is one of the first steps developers take when their code fails, and is an important skill to learn. Not debugging your code is also worth a downvote. To learn why, and for hints on how to debug your code, [see our “No Debugging” page](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).*

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: That actually is an error.

Comment: Thanks Liam :) keep them down votes coming ! glad I asked a question

Comment: I'm trying to help you improve this question. Any one person can only downvote once here, if you have multiple downvotes it means multiple people think your question "is not useful, lacks research effort, etc". I (or anyone else) can't help you because you have not given me enough information to help you. If you want someone to put the effort into solving your problem you need to put some effort in yourself.

Comment: @Amadan yeah, my eyes missed that semicolon's position

Comment: @Liam, what's node bugging? :P Is it like messing up with serverside JavaScript? :D

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when you try to execute your code, you should be seeing a Syntax Error, pointing to the semicolon in `(count--;)`. The reason for this is: `else` expects a statements, if it sees a parenthesis it means the statement is an expression, and in an expression, semicolons can't appear inside parentheses (this is rather simplified). The correct way to write it is either without parentheses (generally frowned upon) as `else count--;`, or with curly braces: `else { count--; }`.

When you fix that error, there will be another one of the same kind, as you seem to systematically use parentheses instead of curly braces after `else`.

After that, your code kind of works. There's questionable comparisons of `card`, that can be a letter or a number, with an integer, but it coincidentally works the way you hope it does (because `'K'`, `'Q'` and `'J'` happen to be evaluated as greater than `7` and `10`.) It would be better to not rely on such magic, and have a translation table between letters and values - or at least, if you're going to rely on magic, comment so that readers are aware you are aware of the magic. Also, `count+=0` is a void statement, it does nothing, and could have been left out. That leaves you with an empty `else if`, but that's not an error. However, it would probably be much more readable if you had `if (card < 7) { count--; } else if (card >= 10) { count++; }`.

Answer (score 0):

stupid mistake's.

answer is below:

```
    var count = 0;

    function cc(card) {
      // Only change code below this line

      if (card < 7){
        count++;
      } else if (card < 10){
        count;
      } else {count--;
  }

      if (count > 0){
        return count + " Bet"
      } else {
        return count + " Hold"
  }
      // Only change code above this line
    }
```